# QT's QMediaRecorder not working - Unable to record from webcam

Tags: c++, qt, video, webcam, video-recording

I've been searching everywhere for a solution to this and I've seen some threads here about this problem but without a solution.

I'm trying to record a video from two different webcams that I have on my computer. I am able to show the video for both of them but the problem is recording. When I try it nothing happens. No file is saved and the states also never change. Bellow I have attached the code that loads the cameras and the code that loads the QMediaRecorders. I also tried with just one of the cameras and it still doesn't work. The QT example "camera" does not work as well, the option for recording is always disabled.

```
void MainWindow::setCamera() {
    foreach (const QCameraInfo &cameraInfo, QCameraInfo::availableCameras()) {
        qDebug() << "Device Name: " + cameraInfo.deviceName();
        qDebug() << "Device Description: " + cameraInfo.description();
        if (cameraInfo.description() == "Integrated Camera")
            camera1 = new QCamera(cameraInfo);
        else if(cameraInfo.description() == "QuickCam for Notebooks Pro")
            camera2 = new QCamera(cameraInfo);
    }
    camera1->setViewfinder(ui->camScreen1);
    camera2->setViewfinder(ui->camScreen2);
    camera1->setCaptureMode(QCamera::CaptureVideo);
    camera2->setCaptureMode(QCamera::CaptureVideo);
    camera1->start();
    camera2->start();

    qDebug() << camera1->status();
    qDebug() << camera1->state();
    qDebug() << camera1->error();
}

void MainWindow::setVideoEncoding() {
    recorder1 = new QMediaRecorder(camera1);
    recorder2 = new QMediaRecorder(camera2);

    QVideoEncoderSettings settings = recorder1->videoSettings();
    settings.setCodec("video/mpeg2");
    settings.setQuality(QMultimedia::LowQuality);
    settings.setResolution(640,480);
    settings.setFrameRate(30.0);

    recorder1->setVideoSettings(settings);
    recorder2->setVideoSettings(settings);

    recorder1->setMetaData(QMediaMetaData::Title, QVariant(QLatin1String("Record1")));
    recorder2->setMetaData(QMediaMetaData::Title, QVariant(QLatin1String("Record2")));

    recorder1->setOutputLocation(QUrl::fromLocalFile(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/" + "testvide1o.mp4"));
    recorder2->setOutputLocation(QUrl::fromLocalFile(QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/" + "testvideo2.mp4"));

    qDebug() << recorder1->status();
    qDebug() << recorder1->state();
    qDebug() << recorder1->error();
}
```

When I press the record button:

```
void MainWindow::toggleRecord(bool startRecord) {
    if(startRecord) {
        recorder1->record();
        recorder2->record();
    }
    else {
        recorder1->stop();
        recorder2->stop();
    }

    qDebug() << recorder1->state();
    qDebug() << recorder1->status();
    qDebug() << recorder1->error();

    qDebug() << recorder2->state();
    qDebug() << recorder2->status();
    qDebug() << recorder2->error();
}
```

The state, status and error are as follows (every time I call them)

**Camera:**
State: `QCamera::UnavailableStatus;`
Status: `QCamera::ActiveState;`
Error: `QCamera::NoError.`

**Recorder:**
State: `QMediaRecorder::UnavailableStatus;`
Status: `QMediaRecorder::StoppedState;`
Error: `QMediaRecorder::NoError.`

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem is that the recording is still not working for windows, as explained [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtmultimedia-windows.html)

I tested it on a mac a it worked fine. To fix this on windows I used the [QtMEL library](http://kibsoft.ru/).